# How to sort data in decreasing order of cgpa in structure with dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Structure and DMA. I want to retrieve all the inserted record in decreasing order of cgpa.
Without sorting it give the result as shown below image.

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct student {
    string name;
    int age;
    float cgpa;
};
void main()
{
    student *ptr;
    int size;
    cout << "enter size \n";
    cin >> size;
    ptr = new student[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " name\n";
        cin >> ptr[i].name;
        cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " age\n";
        cin >> ptr[i].age;
        cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " cgpa\n";
        cin >> ptr[i].cgpa;
    }
    cout << "with out sorting \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << " NAME\tAGE\tCGPA\n";
        cout << ptr[i].name << "\t" << ptr[i].age << "\t" << ptr[i].cgpa << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whP8d.png
```

Comment: What do you mean "without sorting"? Does putting the data into a `std::set` count?

Comment: Unrelated, but you have memory leak, don't use raw pointers, use `std::vector` or `std::set` as mentioned above.

Comment: As mentioned by @fas you have to do `delete [] ptr` at the end to deallocate the pointer to avoid memory leak.

Comment: `std::sort(ptr, ptr + size, [](const student& s1, const student& s2){return s1.cgpa > s2.cgpa;});` -- Anything stopping from using this?

Comment: As surprising as this may sound, sorting an array is exactly the same with or without dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct student {
    string name;
    int age;
    float cgpa;
};
void main() {
    student *ptr;
    int size;
    cout << "enter size \n"; cin >> size;
    ptr = new student[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " name\n";
        cin >> ptr[i].name;
        cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " age\n";
        cin >> ptr[i].age;
        cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " cgpa\n";
        cin >> ptr[i].cgpa;
    }
    string temp1; int temp2;    float temp3;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (ptr[i].cgpa < ptr[j].cgpa)
            {
                temp1 = ptr[j].name;
                ptr[j].name = ptr[i].name;
                ptr[i].name = temp1;

                temp2 = ptr[j].age;
                ptr[j].age = ptr[i].age;
                ptr[i].age = temp2;

                temp3 = ptr[j].cgpa;
                ptr[j].cgpa = ptr[i].cgpa;
                ptr[i].cgpa = temp3;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << " NAME\tAGE\tCGPA\n";
        cout << ptr[i].name << "\t" << ptr[i].age << "\t" << ptr[i].cgpa << endl;
    }
    
    delete[] ptr;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*"Without sorting"* is a bit unclear, but I take that to mean you cannot call `std::sort` directly or use another explicit sorting routine. That leaves you with choosing a container that stores object in sort order based on a compare function (or overload) you provide. Looking at the [Microsoft C++ language conformance table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) for VS2015, it shows all core language features for C++11 supported -- which would include [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

`std::set` allows you to store a sorted set of unique objects. This means you can take input and store the results in a `std::set` based a Compare function you provide. Providing a Compare function that will compare the `cgpa` of each student will then automatically store your `student` objects based `cgpa`.

To make `std::set` available, you simply need to `#include<set>`. Writing the compare function that can be used to store students based on `cgpa` simply requires providing an overload for the `<` operator that takes two of your `student` objects as arguments and then returns `true` when the first argument sorts before the second, `false` otherwise. That can be as simple as:

```
/* overload of < comparing student by cgpa */
bool operator <(const student& a, const student& b) {
    return a.cgpa < b.cgpa;
}
```

A note: unless you are compiling for a micro-controller or embedded system with no Operating System (called a *freestanding environment*), `void main()` is wrong. A standard conforming invocation of `main()` is either `int main(void)` or `int main (int argc, char **argv)` where `argc` is the *argument count* and `argv` your *argument vector* (technically an array of pointers to null-terminated strings where the next pointer after the last argument is set to `NULL` as a sentinel) There are other non-standard extensions added by some compilers like `char **envp` providing a pointer to each of the environment variables.

To declare your set of `student` you need to provide the type `student` and the compare function to be used when inserting students into your set. Since you provide an overload for the less-than operator, you can use `std::less<>` providing one template argument, e.g.

```
int main(void)
{
    /* create std::set of students using std::less for compare */
    std::set<student, std::less<const student&>> students {};
```

And since you are using a container that provides automatic memory management for you, there is no need to know the `size` (or number of students to enter) before hand. You can simply enter as many students as you need and then press <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on Windows to generate a manual `EOF` signifying your end of input. However you do need to ***validate*** every user input by checking the return (stream state) following each input. At minimum you can use:

```
        std::cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " name\n";
        if (!(std::cin >> s.name))  /*  validate all input, ctrl + z to end input */
            break;
```

(**note:** the variable `i` is only needed to show the student number when you prompt for input, all containers provides the `.size()` member function that tell you how many objects are contained within.)

When done taking input, you can use a [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to iterate over each student in your set outputting the desired information. For example:

```
    std::cout << "\nwith out sorting \n";
    for (auto& s : students) {      /* output in order of cgpa w/o sorting */
        std::cout << " NAME\tAGE\tCGPA\n"
                    << s.name << "\t" << s.age << "\t" << s.cgpa << '\n';
    }
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct student {            /* struct student */
    std::string name;
    int age;
    float cgpa;
};

/* overload of < comparing student by cgpa */
bool operator <(const student& a, const student& b) {
    return a.cgpa < b.cgpa;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* create std::set of students using std::less for compare */
    std::set<student, std::less<const student&>> students {};
    
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        student s {};       /* temporary struct to add to set */
        std::cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " name\n";
        if (!(std::cin >> s.name))  /*  validate all input, ctrl + z to end input */
            break;
        std::cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " age\n";
        if (!(std::cin >> s.age))
            break;
        std::cout << "enter student " << i + 1 << " cgpa\n";
        if (!(std::cin >> s.cgpa))
            break;
        students.insert(s); /* insert student in set */
    }
    std::cout << "\nwith out sorting \n";
    for (auto& s : students) {      /* output in order of cgpa w/o sorting */
        std::cout << " NAME\tAGE\tCGPA\n"
                    << s.name << "\t" << s.age << "\t" << s.cgpa << '\n';
    }
}
```

(**note:** Look at [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696). Developing good habits early is a lot easier that trying to break bad ones later...)

(**note 2:** you might consider using `getline(std::cin, s.name)` to take input for the student name so you can handle names with spaces, like `Firstname Lastname`, e.g. `Mickey Mouse`, up to you)

Add `system("pause");` back in to hold your terminal window open as needed.

**Example Use/Output**

Now just enter the student data for as many students as you like and then terminate input by generating a manual `EOF` as described above, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/set_student_grades
enter student 1 name
gates
enter student 1 age
20
enter student 1 cgpa
2.12
enter student 2 name
della
enter student 2 age
21
enter student 2 cgpa
2.00
enter student 3 name
jim
enter student 3 age
30
enter student 3 cgpa
3.12
enter student 4 name

with out sorting
 NAME   AGE     CGPA
della   21      2
 NAME   AGE     CGPA
gates   20      2.12
 NAME   AGE     CGPA
jim     30      3.12
```

This provides a way to store and provide the student data in order of `cgpa` without an explicit `sort`. Of course `std::set` does that for you, but if avoiding an explicit sort was the intent of your program, this is very good option. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It will work fine in VS2015. I just built it in the Microsoft SDK 7.1 (VS 2010 compiler) and aside from changing the range based for loop to one that iterates `for (auto s = students.begin(); s != students.end(); s++)` it worked just fine.